# Command-Line Option to open new chrome process group

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, proxy

I've created a chrome shortcut to start it with some proxy: `--proxy-server="socks5://ipaddress:port"`. However, this does not work if there was already a chrome instance running: new chrome instance will be the same as existing chrome process. The only way to get that `--proxy-server` command line param to be used is to close all chrome instances and then start new process using this shortcut. Reverse is also true: if after that I start regular chrome instance it will use that proxy server config from first launched chrome instance.

Question: how can I start new instance of chrome totally isolated from existing process so that it would start with custom proxy server. I've tried to override `--profile-directory=` and I've tried to start it with incognito: all useless, it still uses whatever proxy settings were set (or weren't) from the time when first instance of chrome was launched.

Comment: Also useful for running multiple Chrome profilers at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the only way that makes it work is to specify alternative user data directory: `--user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data.Proxy"`.
In my case target command line in windows' shortcut was too long (over 256 chars) and I had to set that as an environment variable instead.